# Converting hours, minutes and seconds to seconds in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I was wondering how to safely convert HH:MM:SS to seconds in ruby, given the input will only be in HH:MM:SS (or H:M:S), without days.

Days would have to be in hours already - "168:00:00" instead of "7 days, 00:00:00".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
'12:34:56'.split(':').map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |a, b| a * 60 + b }
=> 45296
```

Comment: If you want to include milliseconds (i.e. parse `"12:34:56.912"`) you can change `to_i` in the map to `to_f`.

Answer (score 3):

```
h, m, s = "168:00:00".split(":").map(&:to_i)
h %= 24
(((h * 60) + m) * 60) + s
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `(((h * 60) + m) * 60) + s`? I think your hours and minutes are flipped.

Comment: @cdownard Oops, you are absolutely right. It was my mistake.

Comment: Running the example code gives 0 (seconds?).

Answer (score -3):

The solution is quite simple:

```
secs = 0
=> 0
"12:34:56".split(":").reverse.each_with_index do |x,y|
  "#{secs} += (#{x.to_i})*(#{60**y})"
  secs += (x.to_i)*(60**y)
end
=> ["56", "34", "12"]
secs
=> 45296
```

No use of `Time` or `DateTime` and no timezone problems!

Cheers!

Comment: No, I post so I can help others who had the same problems as I had.

Comment: What about a bog post?

Comment: In case you mean blog post, then no, I don't have time to have one. Or content. Or both.

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not meet the community standards for solution quality. If the goal of SO is to eliminate beginner-level input then I'm sorry. The question is - shouldn't SO limit the ability to post an answer to only people with a degree and 3 certificates?

Comment: Like really, sorry for trying to give back to community, mainly to those who fail to find the appropriate questions/answers due to the language barrier.

Comment: Clarity is not its strongest point, but using `reverse` is nice to achieve a general solution.